# JSoup Document structure issue

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Try the following....

```
String rq = "http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/ac1afa8d-1a86-4435-9714-0a5e808e4c83?inc=recordings";<br></br>
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(rq).get();
```

You can see in a browser that the tracks are structured as follows...

```
<track><br></br>
    <position>1</position><br></br>
    <length>249000</length><br></br>
    <recording><br></br>
    <title>Hello</title><br></br>
    <length>249000</length><br></br>
    </recording><br></br>
 </track&gt;<br></br>
```

But if you look in the Document it has been restructured to...

```
<track></track><br></br>
<position>1</position><br></br>
<length>249000</length><br></br>
<recording><br></br>
   <title>Hello</title><br></br>
   <length>249000</length><br></br>
</recording><br></br>
```

Any idea what's going on? (using jsoup-1.6.1.jar)
Thanks!

Comment: That's not HTML but XML. Use an XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because the document you are parsing is XML and not HTML.  Jsoup is primarily an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsoup to parse XML like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xmlString, baseInput, Parser.xmlParser());
```